# Eclipse RCP - Opening perspective on button click

Tags: eclipse, button, rcp, perspective

im buliding an eclipse rcp application. i have 2 perspective, Perspective1 which is default open when application is launched and Perspective2.i have a task where i have to open perspective2 on button click and close the opened Perspective1. how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Get the workbench from somewhere, for example:

```java
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
```

Get the workbench window you want to open the perspective in from somewhere, for example:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
```

Show the perspective:

```java
workbench.showPerspective("perspective-id", window);
```